# How can I highlight all lines added/changed between some SVN revisions in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I want this as a very lightweight code review tool (check changes and add comments).  "Annotate" feature in AnkhSVN is very close to my requirements but

- annotation window is not editable to support adding comments
- it cannot be automatically applied to the whole solution

**Edit:**
Better description of my requirements
I have small team of developers and I want to review code from time to time and to add review comments directly to code. I want to see changes from revision N to HEAD directly in Visual Studio code editor, so I can do it. Such lightweight code review process will be completely sufficient for me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/)? Quoting from their features:

> Quick Diff marks changes visually within Visual Studio using color coding. You can see the changes in your source file from the repository version at a glance. There is fast navigation available to move to the next changed section. You never have to open a separate “diff” window to see what you have changed. And you don't have to hunt for changes.

But this is not open sourced like AnkhSVN.

**EDIT**

Since you are looking for code review tools tied to svn you should see these two questions:

[What's the best way to do a code review with Subversion (SVN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99707/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-code-review-with-subversion-svn)

[Best tools for code reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906/best-tools-for-code-reviews)

Comment: Quick Diff shows only changes in working copy. I need something a little bit different. I will try to describe my requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

Most subversion clients will allow you to modify comments if you allow it in your repository, so for each revision you can add comments that in your opinion should be there.  If you need line-by-line, then you might have a problem.